# How to use variable from one collection in another

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to display the 'meetings' collection meetings whose host email (from 'users' collection) contains the phrase 'agu'. Here the meetings' hosts' emails are called from the users collection:

```
var host = meetings.host

db.collection('users').findOne({'_id': new ObjectId(host)}, function(err, doc) {
    var emails = [];
    if (doc.emails) {
        doc.emails.forEach(function(e) {
            emails.push(e.email + (e.primary ? '(P)' : ''));
        });
    }
    var email = emails.join(', ');
```

Here is an example of code finding meetings with the meetings collection attribute of DisplayValue (title) containing the phrase 'fall':

```
function findMeetings(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('meetings').find({
      'name.displayValue': {'$regex': 'fall', '$options': 'i' }
    });
    cursor.count(function(err, count) {
        console.log('count: ' + count);
        var cnt = 0;
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            if (doc != null) {
                findNumberOfNotesByMeeting(db, doc, function() {
                    cnt++;
                    if (cnt >= count) { callback(); }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is what a meetings.attendees attribute looks like:

```
attendees: [{
    email: {type: String, default: ''},
    userId: {type: String, default: ''},
    isPresenter: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    invitationStatus: {type: String, default: ''},
    invitationResent: {type: Boolean, default: false}
}],
```

Here is what the users schema looks like:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
createdOn: { type: Number, default: 0},
updatedOn: { type: Number, default: 0},
emails: [{
    email: { type: String, default: ''},
    confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false},
    primary: { type: Boolean, default: false}
}],
authentication: [{
    token: { type: String, default: ''},
    createdOn: { type: Number, default: 0}
}],
password: {
    salt: { type: String, default: ''},
    hash: { type: String, default: ''}
},
consecutiveFailedLoginAttempts: { type: Number, default: 0},
communicationOptions: {
    customerContact: { type: Boolean, default: false}
},
profileCompleted: { type: Boolean, default: false},
profile: {
    firstName: {
        searchValue: { type: String, default: ''},
        displayValue: { type: String, default: ''}
    },
    lastName: {
        searchValue: { type: String, default: ''},
        displayValue: { type: String, default: ''}
    },
    nickname: { type: String, default: ''},
    companyName: { type: String, default: ''},
    title: { type: String, default: ''},
    location: { type: String, default: ''},
    imageURL: { type: String, default: ''}
},
forgotPassword: {
    token: {type: String, default: ''},
    forgotOn: {type: Number, default: 0}
},
deleteAccount: {
    token: {type: String, default: ''},
    actionOn: {type: Number, default: 0},
    confirmedOn: {type: Number, default: 0}
},
anonymous: {type: Boolean, default: false}
```

});

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some sample documents from both collections that could be used as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: fixed, I hope. Having a hard time with MCV examples with mongo... Anyways, thank you for the help so far @chridam

Also related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151775/export-to-excel-a-unique-list-of-all-an-attribute-fitting-some-criteria)